# C++ go through each character of a wstring and replace it

Tags: c++, wstring

I want to "validate" a wstring and remove undesired character.

This is what I would like to do:

```
wstring wsInput=L"Some Text $$!$§";

wstring wsNew=L"";

for (int i=0;i<wsInput.size();i++)
{
    wstring wsChar=wsInput.CharacterAt(i);
    wsChar = ToValidWString(wsChar); // ToValidWString will return L"" if the character is not among the valid characters
    wsNew.append(wsChar); 
}

return wsNew;
```

But there is no such function ".CharacterAt()" for wstring.
I guess that is for a reason, but I need it anyway.

Can somebody help?

Thank you.

Comment: Keep in mind strings are not arrays, please use the [CharNext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647469(v=vs.85).aspx) function or something similar that does take into account unicode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the operator `[]`. This returns a `wchar`, not a string, but it seems to me this will make your code simpler. So to make things clearer:

```
for (int i=0;i<wsInput.size();i++)
{
    wchar_t wc =wsInput[i]; // sorry for the name it comes from wchar ;)
    ... do stuff...
}
```

EDIT: to get a wstring consisting of the i-th character in the string use `substr`:

```
for (int i=0;i<wsInput.size();i++)
{
    wstring ws = wsInput.substr(i, 1);
    ... do stuff...
}
```

Comment: wchar is not what I need. I really need the wstring.

Comment: @tmighty well then you can use `substr` something like this: `wsInput.substr(i, 1)`

Comment: Ah, thank you very much! substr is what I was looking for. Can you please make that your answer?

Comment: @tmighty I have added this as an edit to my answer. I believe both approach may be useful to a user having similar problems so I left them both in.